# How to do a checklist/to-do list in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to create a checklist/to-do list app in Cakephp.

In the mySQL database I have a column called 'done' which is either true or false.
I have all my tasks in a table.
How do I change the value of that field when I either tick a checkbox or click on the task in the table row?

I want to be able to change this field without having press submit on a  form or reload the page.

Is this possible in Cakephp?

Comment: Yes its possible, use javascript

Comment: See also [sandbox examples](https://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples/)